# Differentiation problem regarding unspecified variable or function.

Tags: derivatives

I am given
$$
y = \alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha}
$$
and asked to prove that
$$
\alpha^2 y'' + \alpha y-2 = 0
$$
but when I use $\alpha$ as a variable I get $y-2 = 0$. Am I missing something? No other explanation is given regarding $\alpha$ or $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong. $y$ is a function of $\alpha$. We have $y'=1-\frac 1 {\alpha^{2}}$ and $y''=\frac 2 {\alpha^{3}}$. Hence $\alpha^{2}y''+\alpha y-2=\frac 2 {\alpha}+\alpha^{2}+1-2$ which is not $0$.

Comment: Sorry, the diferential equation is in fact
$$
\alpha^2 y'' + \alpha y' - 2 = 0
$$
and I thought it was probably a special kind of equation.

Comment: @JesúsPiñera Even then you don't get $0$.